# Known xpath 2.0 processor with jdom support

Tags: xpath, jdom, xpath-2.0

Which xpath 2.0 processors with jdom support are known?

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated saxon with saxon-jdom? (www.saxonica.com)

Answer (score 0):

But the free Version doesn't support Jdom-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what version of XPath it is but JDOM has support for XPath queries.

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html